# Element of fraction field integral over ring of integers

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

In Mollin's Algebraic Number Theory, the author states "Since $F$ is the quotient field of $\mathfrak{O}_F$ [the ring of integers for $F$] then any $\alpha\in F$ is integral over $\mathfrak{O}_F$."

This is part of proving the fact that the ring of integers of a number field is a Dedekind Domain. In particular, it aims to prove that $\mathfrak{O}_F$ is integrally closed.

However, unless I'm missing something, the statement appears false. $\mathbb{Q}$ is the fraction field for $\mathbb{Z}$, which is in turn the ring of integers for $\mathbb{Q}$. However, not every element of $\mathbb{Q}$ is integral (the solution to a monic polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$. Am I missing something?

Comment: You are correct that the statement is totally wrong: $\mathcal O_F$ is integrally closed, so the only elements of $F$ that are integral over $\mathcal O_F$ are elements of $\mathcal O_F$. There are many algebraic number theory books out there, so if you really can't figure out what Mollin had meant to say in that part of the proof, just read the proof in other books.

Comment: I read the proof at the end of page 42, and as @KCd points out, it is complicated and wrong. I personally recomend Marcus' "Number Fields", chapter 3 (actually the entire book is wonderfull).